# Newly inserted rows deleted when creating a trigger in MySql

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, yii

I m trying to fetch the IDs of all last inserted rows. For that i was created a trigger as follows;

```
CREATE TRIGGER mytable_insert
AFTER INSERT ON mytable
FOR EACH ROW SET @insertIDs = CONCAT_WS(',', @insertIDs, NEW.id)
```

then in the program section the code is like follows

```
$sql="INSERT INTO `table` ({columns}) VALUES({values})";
$command=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
if($command->execute()){
    $sql='SELECT @insertIDs AS "Inserted_IDs"';
    $command=Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql);
    $rows=$command->queryAll();
    var_dump($rows);
}
```

Here I got some IDs....but the problem is i could not find those rows in the database...Dont know what is the mistake.....help needed....

Answer (score 0):

What is your sql syntax?

```
SELECT @insertIDs AS "Inserted_IDs"
```

Where "From" ? (SELECT * FROM T;)

Answer (score 0):

The `@insertIDs` is a user variable, which is visible in current session; so, you may create the different variables with the same name in other MySQL sessions.

It looks like your code uses more then one session, and therefore showы unexpected result. Check that your code uses one session ( I mean MySQL connection) to execute INSERT and SELECT query.

Also, you can try this code in MySQL command-line console, it must work.